# Local Html Page become blank after several load

Tags: android, html

I just suffered from a case that some local html file will become blank page after reload/ being ignored for some period of time. However, the html file will works fine again in a new tab.

It is remarkable that the page contains no Javascript.

Besides, it is also reported that the same set of local html will become blank page rarely and randomly when loading in Android Webview. The permission configuration and folder path (using:file:/// as the beginning of the url) are both valid and exists in the machine. The Webview has set clearcache to true before each loading.

I have also checked the page that, all the page elements are still there but they cannot be displayed.

It is remarkable that, reload the webpage will never work.

Here is the capture of the page after it become blank page.
[image]

Any idea?

**EDIT 1**
source code of Android loading the local html file

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.setPadding(40, 40, 0, 0);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
wv.clearCache(true);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String filePath = ext.toString() + "/some_folder/";
wv.loadUrl("file:///" + filePath + "HTML Forms/form1.html");
vh.webLinearLayout.addView(wv,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Are you using a android webserver app to load the pages?..Or is it a standalone webview app?

Comment: standalone webview app

Comment: Did you download it from the platstore or it's your own creation?

Comment: One of the project we built.
however, as mentioned in the question, it is just a rare case, but once it appear, the user need to clear the apps cache or uninstall & install the app to make the webview works again.

Comment: how do you load the webview? post the relevant code

Comment: In Desktop, i just simply opened the html file in Url area. i will post the android code later.